# Unable to redirect to the specified component when the path is empty

Tags: angular

I have written a code where it redirects to a specific component at the start of an application.

```
const routes: Routes = [
    {path: 'home', component: HomeComponent},
    {path: 'content', loadChildren: 'app/components/content/content.module#ContentModule'},
    {path: 'setup', loadChildren: 'app/components/setup/setup.module#SetupModule'},
    {path: 'publish', component: PublishComponent},
    {path: '', redirectTo: 'home', pathMatch: 'full'},
    {path: '**', redirectTo: 'home'}

];
```

Its not redirecting to HomeComponet when the path is ''. Its only redirecting when the URL contains 'home'. Could someone please help me where Acutally I went wrong

Comment: It's not redirecting when the path is what?

Comment: When the path is '' i.e localhost:4200/

Comment: I believe you are loading app.component.html as your root page when its serving. Whatever is in that it will load as the first instance. Try removing the 'pathMatch: 'full'

Comment: If I remove the pathMatch, I am getting the following error:

Error: Invalid configuration of route '{path: "", redirectTo: "home"}': please provide 'pathMatch'. The default value of 'pathMatch' is 'prefix', but often the intent is to use 'full'

Comment: Did you try having `{path: '', redirectTo: 'home', pathMatch: 'full'},` at the top of the routes ?

Comment: Yes i did that too

Answer (score 0):

I found out the error. But I didn't  understand why order of AppRoutingModule is important in imports

```
imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        BrowserAnimationsModule,
        HttpClientModule,
        MaterialModule,
        FlexLayoutModule,
        FormsModule,
        SetupModule,
        ContentModule,
        CoreModule,
      AppRoutingModule, //The last four modules are custom modules


    ],
```

Instead of placing AppRoutingModule last, I shifted it after the FormsModule.

i.e

```
imports: [
            BrowserModule,
            BrowserAnimationsModule,
            HttpClientModule,
            MaterialModule,
            FlexLayoutModule,
            FormsModule,
            AppRoutingModule,//Shifted Here
            SetupModule,
            ContentModule,
            CoreModule


        ],
```

By changing this, It's redirecting to HomeComponent whenever the path is empty